# Change domain for Pull Request environments in Azure Static Web Apps

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app

Is it possible to change the domain for which Pull Request environments are built to? Currently we have our main branch built to a custom domain `https://dev.mycompany.com` and PR environments are built to the generated domain `https://icy-flower-07e440303-{Pull Request ID}.westeurope.azurestaticapps.net`. I would like them to be something like `https://{Pull Request ID}.dev.mycompany.com` so that our CORS rules still applies.

Answer (score -1):

- you can apply a custom domain directly to the static app. To do this you need to make a dns entry in the azure dns or any other dns registry then configure the static app to use the custom domain.
- Dns registry can be done just by going to the azure dns in the portal click on the `+` button and fill the required details
- Then you can configure the static app by providing the custom domain in the setting under custom domain option.

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/custom-domain-azure-dns).

Comment: We've done just this but Azure still makes the PR's against the generated url. https://i.imgur.com/lg412mG.png